# Remove series in array if ALL values equal 0

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to review an array called `$rows`. For each distinct series in `ifDesc`, if **all** `Octets` are `0` then remove them, however if a single entry is > 0, keep the entire series including the 0's for that distinct `ifDesc`

I attempted to loop through this using PHP or JavaScript (as it is passed as an ajax response) using foreach however I was having issues working with the distinct `ifDesc`

This is the array json encoded for readability.

```
0: {id: "40", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:10"}
1: {id: "87", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:10"}
2: {id: "134", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:09"}
3: {id: "181", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:09"}
4: {id: "228", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:09"}
5: {id: "275", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:09"}
6: {id: "322", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:09"}
7: {id: "369", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:09"}
8: {id: "416", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:09"}
9: {id: "463", ifDesc: "imq0 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:11"}
10: {id: "36", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:09"}
11: {id: "83", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:09"}
12: {id: "130", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:08"}
13: {id: "177", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:08"}
14: {id: "224", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:08"}
15: {id: "271", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:09"}
16: {id: "318", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:08"}
17: {id: "365", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:08"}
18: {id: "412", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:08"}
19: {id: "459", ifDesc: "lo - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:10"}
20: {id: "37", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:09"}
21: {id: "84", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.021765, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:09"}
22: {id: "131", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.029837, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:08"}
23: {id: "178", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.055927, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:08"}
24: {id: "225", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.043918, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:08"}
25: {id: "272", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.029381, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:09"}
26: {id: "319", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.021934, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:09"}
27: {id: "366", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.023848, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:09"}
28: {id: "413", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.001438, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:08"}
29: {id: "460", ifDesc: "Port1 - In", Octets: 0.000928, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:10"}
30: {id: "42", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:10"}
31: {id: "89", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000001, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:11"}
32: {id: "136", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000001, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:09"}
33: {id: "183", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000003, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:09"}
34: {id: "230", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000001, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:09"}
35: {id: "277", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000002, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:10"}
36: {id: "324", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000001, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:10"}
37: {id: "371", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000001, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:10"}
38: {id: "418", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000001, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:09"}
39: {id: "465", ifDesc: "Port1.100 - In", Octets: 0.000001, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:11"}
40: {id: "41", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:10"}
41: {id: "88", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000033, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:10"}
42: {id: "135", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000033, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:09"}
43: {id: "182", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000033, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:09"}
44: {id: "229", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000033, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:09"}
45: {id: "276", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000038, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:10"}
46: {id: "323", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000034, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:09"}
47: {id: "370", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000033, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:09"}
48: {id: "417", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000033, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:09"}
49: {id: "464", ifDesc: "Port1.2 - In", Octets: 0.000033, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:11"}
50: {id: "38", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:09"}
51: {id: "85", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0.125069, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:10"}
52: {id: "132", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0.187321, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:08"}
53: {id: "179", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0.13348, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:08"}
54: {id: "226", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0.284196, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:09"}
55: {id: "273", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:09"}
56: {id: "320", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:09"}
57: {id: "367", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:09"}
58: {id: "414", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:09"}
59: {id: "461", ifDesc: "Port2 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:10"}
60: {id: "39", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:10"}
61: {id: "86", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.000056, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:10"}
62: {id: "133", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.000299, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:09"}
63: {id: "180", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.00072, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:09"}
64: {id: "227", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.003257, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:09"}
65: {id: "274", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.000062, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:09"}
66: {id: "321", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.000042, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:09"}
67: {id: "368", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.000074, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:09"}
68: {id: "415", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.000037, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:09"}
69: {id: "462", ifDesc: "Port8 - In", Octets: 0.000063, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:10"}
70: {id: "43", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:10"}
71: {id: "90", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.119396, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:11"}
72: {id: "137", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.178453, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:10"}
73: {id: "184", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.126522, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:10"}
74: {id: "231", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.356846, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:10"}
75: {id: "278", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.156991, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:10"}
76: {id: "325", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.04118, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:10"}
77: {id: "372", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.143545, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:10"}
78: {id: "419", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.014859, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:10"}
79: {id: "466", ifDesc: "reds2 - In", Octets: 0.010649, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:11"}
80: {id: "40", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:10"}
81: {id: "87", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:10"}
82: {id: "134", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:09"}
83: {id: "181", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:09"}
84: {id: "228", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:09"}
85: {id: "275", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0.000061, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:09"}
86: {id: "322", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:09"}
87: {id: "369", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:09"}
88: {id: "416", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:09"}
89: {id: "463", ifDesc: "imq0 - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 17:00:11"}
90: {id: "36", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 14:45:09"}
91: {id: "83", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:00:09"}
92: {id: "130", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:15:08"}
93: {id: "177", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:30:08"}
94: {id: "224", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 15:45:08"}
95: {id: "271", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:00:09"}
96: {id: "318", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:15:08"}
97: {id: "365", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:30:08"}
98: {id: "412", ifDesc: "lo - Out", Octets: 0, date: "2019-07-12 16:45:08"}
```

As this data is being passed to a chart I am hoping to eliminate series of lines where all values are 0 at the bottom of my chart.
In the above array I hope to remove `imq0 - In`, `lo - In` & `lo - Out` as the sum of all `Octets` = 0.

There is a little more complexity as the data stored isn't what you see, there are calculations prior to building the array, see below:

```
$SQLIn = "SELECT id, CONCAT(ifDesc, \" - In\") as ifDesc, ifInOctets AS Octets, date FROM table WHERE applianceKey = 'XXXX' AND date between (CURTIME() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) and CURTIME() ORDER BY ifDesc, date";
$SQLOut = "SELECT id, CONCAT(ifDesc, \" - Out\") as ifDesc, ifOutOctets AS Octets, date FROM table WHERE applianceKey = 'XXXX' AND date between (CURTIME() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) and CURTIME() ORDER BY ifDesc, date";
$ResultsIn = mysqli_query($dbST, $SQLIn) or die();
$ResultsOut = mysqli_query($dbSTS, $SQLOut) or die();
$SQLRowsIn = mysqli_num_rows($ResultsIn);
$SQLRowsOut = mysqli_num_rows($ResultsOut);
$curOct = 0; $prevOct = 0; $curIf = ''; $prevIf = '';
$rows = array();
if ($SQLRowsIn > 0) {
while ($rowIn = MySQLi_fetch_assoc($ResultsIn)) {
    $curIf = $rowIn['ifDesc'];
    $curOct = $rowIn['Octets'];
    if ($curIf === $prevIf) { $clc = $curOct-$prevOct; }
    else { $clc = $curOct-$curOct; }
    if ($clc < 0) { $clc = $curOct-$prevOct+4294967295; }
    $B = $clc*8;
    $kB = $B/1000;
    $mB = $kB/1000;
    $mBps = $mB/900;
    $rowIn['Octets'] = $mBps;
    $rows[] = $rowIn;
    $prevIf = $curIf;
    $prevOct = $curOct;
}
$curOct = 0; $prevOct = 0; $curIf = ''; $prevIf = '';
while ($rowOut = MySQLi_fetch_assoc($ResultsOut)) {
    $curIf = $rowOut['ifDesc'];
    $curOct = $rowOut['Octets'];
    if ($curIf === $prevIf) { $clc = $curOct-$prevOct; }
    else { $clc = $curOct-$curOct; }
    if ($clc < 0) { $clc = $curOct-$prevOct+4294967295; }
    $B = $clc*8;
    $kB = $B/1000;
    $mB = $kB/1000;
    $mBps = $mB/900;
    $rowOut['Octets'] = $mBps;
    $rows[] = $rowOut;
    $prevIf = $curIf;
    $prevOct = $curOct;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: So basically you want to group by `ifDesc` and then check `Octets`? Where does this data load from?

Comment: Usually it's better to do the filtering server-side rather than dump a ton of junk to the client it doesn't need.

Comment: where is this `foreach` loop code that's in issue, it should be posted too

Comment: I've added my query and further calculations needed for this data in the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that I would do is get all the `ifDesc`s first. After you gather all of em, you can start processing the actual array to remove batches of `ifDesc`s that has zero sum.

```
$ifDescs = array_unique(array_column($rows, 'ifDesc')); // get all ifDescs
foreach ($ifDescs as $currentIfDesc) { // loop each ifDesc batches
    $current_batch = []; // set initial batch of ifDesc type for temporary container
    foreach ($rows as $k => $row) { // group them first
        if ($row['ifDesc'] === $currentIfDesc) {
            $current_batch[$k] = $row;
        }
    }
    $non_zero_octets = array_sum(array_column($current_batch, 'Octets')) > 0; // get all octets of the current batch iteration, and check if its greater than one when summed
    if (!$non_zero_octets) { // if not greater than zero
        $rows = array_diff_key($rows, array_keys($current_batch)); // remove em using all the keys
    }
}
```

But for what it's worth. I agree with Barmar's solution using queries so that it'll scale better.

Comment: Hi Ghost, thank you this has worked for me. I did have to reindex the array for the chart to work, I added `$rows = array_values($rows);`

Comment: @kfear did you try any of the other 2 solutions?

Comment: @kfear yes you'll need to reindex it since it unset some keys on the original array making it not sequential anymore. sure glad this helped

Comment: Hi @Ghost - I was getting some odd results where it would only remove the first series in the array, so I edited so if the series was > 0 it would add to another array then `json_encode()` it.

I will add my answer to my original post

Answer (score 3):

Change your query to filter them out.

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(t1.ifDesc, " - In") as ifDesc, ifInOctets AS Octets, date 
FROM table AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ifDesc
    FROM table
    WHERE applianceKey = 'XXXX' AND date between (CURTIME() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) and CURTIME() 
        AND ifInOctets != 0
) AS t2 ON t1.ifDesc = t2.ifDesc
WHERE applianceKey = 'XXXX' AND date between (CURTIME() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) and CURTIME()
ORDER BY ifDesc, date
```

The subquery returns only `ifDesc` that have at least one non-zero row.

Comment: Hi Barmar, there is more complexity with calculations in PHP I have added where the previous row is calculated with the following to gain the `Octet` value. So ideally if we can do this in PHP it will be better

Comment: Given the calculation happens on the previous row only if the ifDesc is the same, how could/would we achieve this in MySQL ? I have my answer for PHP if you have time it would be very handy to know?
We wort on ifDesc then Date, it would calculate on the last sample data depending on the datetime stamp (date column)

Comment: You can use `@variable` to save values from one row to the next in a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Ghost's answer, we calculated the sum of each distinct `ifDesc` and if this was > 0 we added to a new array.

```
$ifDescs = array_unique(array_column($rows, 'ifDesc'));
$recalculatedRows = [];
foreach ($ifDescs as $currentIfDesc) {
    $current_batch = [];
    foreach ($rows as $k => $row) {
        if ($row['ifDesc'] === $currentIfDesc) {
            $current_batch[$k] = $row;
        }
    }
    if (array_sum(array_column($current_batch, 'Octets')) > 0) { //sum of Octets > 0 ?
        foreach ($current_batch as $r) { //if yes, loop through $current_batch
            $recalculatedRows[] = $r; //adding series to new array
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($recalculatedRows);
```